# Kafka stream real time video processing

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

We are looking for real time video streaming large size of frame

Currently we are using Kafka Python which sends uuid over topic and mongo for store large data and uuid

At consumer side we receive uuid based on that get associated frame data fr mongo then pass to process

But it takes more time from entire pipeline
Producer side
Capture frame
Generate uuid
Store uuid and frame array in mongo
Send uuid on kafka topic

Consumer side
Get MSG.value as uuid
Using uuid get frame array data from mongo
Delete record after received
Pass frame to our process function

I have question is there any other way to reduce this pipeline time

Capture frame size > 18mb
So encode it in bytes using cv2.imencode png form
So after that reduced to 5 mb

Answer (score 0):

You may try not to send the generated uuid over Kafka. In this case may be you can generate a random identifier and assign it to a frame and send that identifier from producer to consumer. Meanwhile in background thread your producer can do some compression and generate uuid and array as well as store it against the identifier.

So once the consumer gets the identifier, it can just find out the uuid by querying db using the identifier received, if uuid has been already generated.

We just offloading the big task to background and sending just an identifier in Kafka to make it fast.

Comment: But It may be chances of loss of frame if uuid identifier received before compression and store procedure completed at producer side

Comment: is there any option to do store the whole into any cheap storage options and thus avoiding compression?!